# Adding multiple libraries on Android

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to add multiples libraries on Android, but every one of them have the support library v4, and need them. I want to add : `android-support-v7-appcompact`, `facebookSDK`, `PullToRefresh`, `google-play-services_lib`.
I have DEX errors and NoClassDef errors every time.

Comment: What is your problem then ?

Comment: check extras inside sdk folder                                  D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

Comment: When i use all of them, i have either a multiple DEX error or a NoClassFound error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each project right click > Android Tools > Add Support Library

Although the support library is already added to the project it will download and install the latest version of the support library.

If you do this for each library project you should no longer see the error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the support library versions are not same there'll be error. 
Either copy one of the support library v4 to all of them or delete all of the support libraries and just leave one of them